# Как запустить background task в discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как запустить background task в discord.py?
При например таком <s>коде</s> минимально воспроизводимом примере:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')

bot.run('***********************************')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.tasks import loop

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')

@loop(seconds=1)
async def bg_task():
    pass # doing smth

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')

bg_task.start()
bot.run('***********************************')
```